# Running a process inside a virtual file system?

Tags: c++, qt, symlink, virtualfilesystem

What I'm trying to achieve is to run a program, which thinks a folder exists within its own folder while actually the folder is somewhere else on the system.

So my program would launch a process and say to the process: Folder A which is at C:\A is within your own directory at C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeProgram\A

So the "virtual" directory would only be visible to that process.

I'm using Qt to program my program, so if there are any Qt functions I could use that would be great (in relation to portability). However, plan C++ or any windows-bound API's would be fine.

I was thinking about NTFS junctions or symbolic links but I would have no idea how to create either of those in C++, let alone bind them to a specific process.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

In relation to the above, I've found this question: https://superuser.com/questions/234422/does-windows7-support-symbolic-links-folder-shortcuts. However, it only shows how to perform the required actions from the command-line and it wouldn't be process bound.

**EDIT 2:**

Some extra information: I'm trying to create a virtual directory that is made up of a couple of other directories but then merged (I'm using a priority system to decide which files "win" from other files). These merged directories would then appear to the target process as one directory containing the merged files.

Comment: Are you talking about symlinks?

Comment: I think so, however I need the links to be visible only to the target process and create them using C++.

Comment: One method is to hook the underlying file system API (CreateFile, FindFirstFile, etc.) and perform the redirection there.  If you go this route, I'd recommend checking out Microsoft's Detours library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm going to stick with Window's mklink command. It seems to suit my needs the best.

What I'm going to do is use QFile::link() on all operating systems that aren't Windows, and QProcess with mklink on windows. This should work on every operating system.

For a good example look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21013935/979732

Answer (score 0):

Such tasks are accomplished by use of a filesystem filter driver. The driver intercepts OS requests going to the filesystem and lets you insert your own virtual files and directories into the existing directory on the disk. Filter driver can be an overkill for your particular task, though.

Detours approach mentioned in comments requires system-wide hooking of file APIs and will slowdown the whole system(filesystem filter driver is attached to one disk and it's a documented approach, so it's faster and more robust).