# Qt5, symbolic link to a folder

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qprocess, qfile

A dupe-ish question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011063/qt-create-link-between-folders), which (possibly) has got an outdated answer, as I can't get it to work in Qt5.

I wish to create a symbolic link to a folder for a result similar to `QFile::link()`. Given that `QDir` doesn't have an equivalent function, `QProcess` (or an external library) seems like the way out if I'm up to snuff. How would this be managed in Qt5?

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "symbolic link" here? Windows supports Unix-like hard and symbolic links, but in practice those features are rarely used.  I don't believe Qt supports either, but you could always use the Win32 API directly.

Comment: I ended up using the Win32 API. I had that in mind at first, but I had trouble understanding the msdn at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it cannot be done in Qt, so I ended up using the Win32 API instead. Specifically the `CreateSymbolicLink()` [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: std::filesystem::create_directory_symlink() can be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are shortcuts and hardlinks on Windows. I think `mklink` refers to hardlinks.

It works for shortcuts:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile dir("D:\\source-dir");
    bool ok = dir.link("D:\\target-dir.lnk");

    if (ok)
    {
        qDebug() << "yeah!";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Did not work :(";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In this case you will find a shortcut in the Explorer but you cannot access the file `D:\source-dir\Bitmap.bmp` by typing `D:\target-dir\Bitmap.bmp`