# Double-quote an argument passed to QProcess::execute?

Tags: c++, escaping, qt5, double-quotes, qprocess

I'm creating symbolic links on Windows using QProcess:

```
QStringList mklink = { "/c", "mklink" };
if(QFileInfo(src).isDir()) mklink << "/d";
mklink << dst << src;

if(QProcess::execute("cmd", mklink) == 0) result = SUCCESS;
```

This works properly when the argument/path contains no special characters.
It also works when an argument/path contains special characters *and* spaces, because the argument is properly double-quoted by QProcess.

The problem is, this doesn't happen when an argument/path *doesn't* contain spaces, and consequently any special characters aren't escaped.

I've tried manually adding double-quotes:

```
if(!path.contains(" ")) path.append("\"").prepend("\"");
-also tried-
if(!path.contains(" ")) path.append('"').prepend('"');
```

But in both cases the output turns out to be `\C:\path\without\space\`. The first and last backslashes are the escape character from the added double-quotes.

One alternative is using [`QProcess::setNativeArguments()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setNativeArguments):

```
QProcess cmd(this);

QString mklink = "/c mklink";
if(QFileInfo(src).isDir()) mklink += " /d";
mklink += " \""+dst+"\" \""+src+"\"";

cmd.setNativeArguments(mklink);
cmd.start("cmd");
if(cmd.waitForFinished() && cmd.exitStatus() == QProcess::NormalExit && cmd.exitCode() == 0)
    result = SUCCESS;
```

This works, but I would like to stick to `QProcess::execute`, because I can use it statically.

The easiest method would be using WinAPI's [`CreateSymbolicLinkA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinka), <del>but it isn't available in MinGW 5.3.0</del>.

**To sum up, my question is: how can I properly double-quote an argument passed to `QProcess::execute`?**

Comment: You should probably have a look at the `Windows` specific comments in the [`QProcess::start`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) documentation.

Comment: I already tried using `setNativeArguments`, but it doesn't seem to work with `QProcess:execute` (or I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: `QProcess::execute` is a static member so there's no way (as far as I'm aware) of using it in conjunction with `QProcess::setNativeArguments`.  You need to use `QProcess::start` instead.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'd like to avoid using `start` though. `execute` offers a very simple way of waiting for the result.

Comment: Why do you use `QProcess`, i.e. `cmd.exe` with internal command `mklink`? Why do you not use in your C++ code the Windows kernel library function which `cmd.exe` uses to create a symbolic link - [CreateSymbolicLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinka)? See also [Qt5, symbolic link to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270848/qt5-symbolic-link-to-a-folder) and [Qt create Link between folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011063/).

Comment: `CreateSymbolicLink` isn't available in the version of MinGW I'm using unfortunately. Those two links don't provide any other  answers as far as I can see (except what @G.M. suggested).

Comment: If this is all about filesystem utilities what about [boost::filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html)?  Is that an option?

Comment: I suppose, but I'd only be using it for this specific case, so then I'd be better off just using `QProcess:start`